# How to change the mantissa separator for PGFPlots contour plot labels?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys, groupplots

How can I change the mantissa separator in my MWE from \cdot to \times?

The MWE needs to be compiled with the `-shell-escape` flag.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}%
%
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{subcaption}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}%
  \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}%
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}%
\usepackage{filecontents}%
%
\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
a,b,c
100,1,1E+16
100,2,2E+17
100,3,5E+18

200,1,1E+16
200,2,2E+15
200,3,5E+14

300,1,1E+14
300,2,2E+13
300,3,5E+12
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
a,b,c
100,1,3
100,2,4
100,3,5

200,1,2
200,2,3
200,3,3

300,1,1
300,2,2
300,3,2
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[%
      width=0.35\textwidth,%
      title style={%
        at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},%
        below=4ex,%
        text width=0.35\textwidth,%
      },%
      group style={%
        group size=1 by 2,%
        horizontal sep=4em,vertical sep=13ex,%
      },%
      scale only axis,%
      tick scale binop=\times,%
      xmin={100},xmax={300},%
      ymin={1},ymax={3},%
      view={0}{90},%
      colormap/viridis,%
    ]%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zminA}{12}% "12" = 1.E+12
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zmaxA}{18}%
      %
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zminB}{1}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zmaxB}{5}%
      %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      % subfig 1 %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      \nextgroupplot[%
        title={\subcaption{}},%
        %
        zmode=log,log base z=10,zminorticks=false,%
        zmin={1.E\zminA},zmax={1.E\zmaxA},%
        %
        xlabel={X1},ylabel={Y1},zlabel={Z1},%
        %
        point meta rel=per plot,%
        point meta min={1.E\zminA},point meta max={1.E\zmaxA},%
        colorbar,%
        colorbar style={
          ymode=log,
          ymin={1.E\zminA},ymax={1.E\zmaxA},%
          yminorticks=false,%
          ylabel={Z1},%
        },%
      ]%
        \addplot3[%
          surf,%
          point meta min={\zminA},point meta max={\zmaxA},%
        ]%
          table[%
            x=a,y=b,z=c,%
            col sep=comma,%
          ]{data1.dat};%
          %
        \addplot3[%
          % modified version of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193707
          contour/label node code/.code={%
            \node{%
              \pgfkeys{%
                /pgf/fpu=true,%
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                sci,%
                % sci generic={%
                %   mantissa sep=\times,%
                %   exponent={10^{##1}},%
                % },%
              }%
              \pgfmathpow{10}{##1}%
              \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
            };%
          },%
          contour gnuplot={%
            draw color=black,%
            levels={4.E14,2.E15,3.E16},% random levels for test
          },%
        ]%
          table[%
            x=a,y=b,z=c,%
            col sep=comma,%
          ]{data1.dat};%
          %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      % subfig 2 %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      \nextgroupplot[%
        title={\subcaption{}},%
        colorbar,%
        colorbar style={
            ylabel={Z2},%
        },%
        zmin={\zminB},zmax={\zmaxB},%
        ztick={\zminB,\zmaxB},%
        %
          xlabel={X2},ylabel={Y2},zlabel={Z2},%
      ]%
      %
        \addplot3[%
          surf,%
          point meta min=\zminB,point meta max=\zmaxB,%
        ]%
          table[%
            x=a,y=b,z=c,%
            col sep=comma,%
          ]{data2.dat};%
          %
        \addplot3[%
          contour gnuplot={%
            draw color=black,%
            contour label style={%
              every node/.append style={text=black}
            },%
          },%
          point meta min=\zminB,point meta max=\zmaxB,%
        ]%
          table[%
            x=a,y=b,z=c,%
            col sep=comma,%
          ]{data2.dat};%
          %
    \end{groupplot}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\caption{my caption}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

I tried to adapt [Alex's contour label manipulation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193707/194307) to

```
contour/label node code/.code={%
  \node{%
    \pgfkeys{%
      /pgf/fpu=true,%
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
      sci,%
      sci generic={%
        mantissa sep=\times,%
        exponent={10^{##1}},%
      },%
    }%
    \pgfmathpow{10}{##1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
  };%
},%
```

Unfortunately, this yields a wrong exponent. Skipping the `exponent` setting in `sci generic` does not work either.

Comment: Isn't the dot here just the decimal indicator, so you could leave it out or use e.g. 1.0E+15?

Comment: I guess you are talking about the formatting of the third column in data1.dat. The dot does not matter. I removed it for clarity. As you can see, the MWE yields the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can always use `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber` and `\pgfmathfloattomacro` to decompose numbers in their "atoms" and recombine them in any way you want. This may not be the quickest way to achieve this but it is very general.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}%
%
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{subcaption}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}%
  \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}%
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}%
\usepackage{filecontents}%
%
\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
a,b,c
100,1,1E+16
100,2,2E+17
100,3,5E+18

200,1,1E+16
200,2,2E+15
200,3,5E+14

300,1,1E+14
300,2,2E+13
300,3,5E+12
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
a,b,c
100,1,3
100,2,4
100,3,5

200,1,2
200,2,3
200,3,3

300,1,1
300,2,2
300,3,2
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[%
      width=0.35\textwidth,%
      title style={%
        at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},%
        below=4ex,%
        text width=0.35\textwidth,%
      },%
      group style={%
        group size=1 by 2,%
        horizontal sep=4em,vertical sep=13ex,%
      },%
      scale only axis,%
      tick scale binop=\times,%
      xmin={100},xmax={300},%
      ymin={1},ymax={3},%
      view={0}{90},%
      colormap/viridis,%
    ]%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zminA}{12}% "12" = 1.E+12
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zmaxA}{18}%
      %
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zminB}{1}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zmaxB}{5}%
      %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      % subfig 1 %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      \nextgroupplot[%
        title={\subcaption{}},%
        %
        zmode=log,log base z=10,zminorticks=false,%
        zmin={1.E\zminA},zmax={1.E\zmaxA},%
        %
        xlabel={X1},ylabel={Y1},zlabel={Z1},%
        %
        point meta rel=per plot,%
        point meta min={1.E\zminA},point meta max={1.E\zmaxA},%
        colorbar,%
        colorbar style={
          ymode=log,
          ymin={1.E\zminA},ymax={1.E\zmaxA},%
          yminorticks=false,%
          ylabel={Z1},%
        },%
      ]%
        \addplot3[%
          surf,%
          point meta min={\zminA},point meta max={\zmaxA},%
        ]%
          table[%
            x=a,y=b,z=c,%
            col sep=comma,%
          ]{data1.dat};%
          %
        \addplot3[%
          % modified version of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193707
          contour/label node code/.code={%
            \node{%
              \pgfkeys{%
                /pgf/fpu=true,%
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed
                %sci,%
                % sci generic={%
                %   mantissa sep=\times,%
                %   exponent={10^{##1}},%
                % },%
              }%
              \pgfmathpow{10}{##1}%
              \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfmathresult}%
              \pgfmathfloattomacro{\pgfmathresult}{\F}{\M}{\E}%
              $\pgfmathprintnumber{\M}\times10^{\E}$%
            };%
          },%
          contour gnuplot={%
            draw color=black,%
            levels={4.E14,2.E15,3.E16},% random levels for test
          },%
        ]%
          table[%
            x=a,y=b,z=c,%
            col sep=comma,%
          ]{data1.dat};%
          %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      % subfig 2 %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      \nextgroupplot[%
        title={\subcaption{}},%
        colorbar,%
        colorbar style={
            ylabel={Z2},%
        },%
        zmin={\zminB},zmax={\zmaxB},%
        ztick={\zminB,\zmaxB},%
        %
          xlabel={X2},ylabel={Y2},zlabel={Z2},%
      ]%
      %
        \addplot3[%
          surf,%
          point meta min=\zminB,point meta max=\zmaxB,%
        ]%
          table[%
            x=a,y=b,z=c,%
            col sep=comma,%
          ]{data2.dat};%
          %
        \addplot3[%
          contour gnuplot={%
            draw color=black,%
            contour label style={%
              every node/.append style={text=black}
            },%
          },%
          point meta min=\zminB,point meta max=\zmaxB,%
        ]%
          table[%
            x=a,y=b,z=c,%
            col sep=comma,%
          ]{data2.dat};%
          %
    \end{groupplot}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\caption{my caption}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!